# No logro deserializar un string Base64

Tags: c#, android, imagen, xamarin, recyclerview

Estoy utilizando un RecyclerView (`C# Xamarin.Android`) en donde el adaptador carga desde 2 listas el texto detalle y el thumbnail, respectivamente.

Al ejecutarse se cargan bien los textos, pero no las imágenes, me da error, si le pongo otras imágenes Base64 de prueba algunas si las carga y algunas no, también revise si las imágenes Base64 de los thumbnails originales están bien con un decoder online y ahi si las carga sin problema. No entiendo que pasa.

El error es:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
> character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
> among the padding characters.

Ya revise y este string no lleva dos simbolos `=` juntos ni caracteres no permitidos.

Les dejo un ejemplo de como deserializo los thumbnails:

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            try
            {
                StoriesHolder hh = holder as StoriesHolder;

                //Textos
                hh.txtTitle.Text = VarGlobal.StoriesTitulo[position];

                //Imagen
                byte[] image64 = Convert.FromBase64String(imagenBase64);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(image64, 0, image64.Length);
            hh.imgIcono.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

                hh.itemClickListener = this;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string LineErrorNumber = "Error en linea: " + Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7) + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

La variable imagenBase64 tiene este string.

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFRAWIB0iIiAdHx8kKDQsJCYxJx8fLT0tMTU3Ojo6Iys/RD84QzQ5OjcBCgoKDQwNGg8PGjclHyU3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3N//AABEIAHAAcAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAABBQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAQIDBAYABwj/xAA5EAACAQMCAwUFBgYCAwAAAAABAgMABBEFIQYSMRNBUYGRIjJhcaEUQlLB0fAHFSMzgrFy8RaSov/EABoBAAMBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIEBQMBAAb/xAAjEQADAAIBBQACAwAAAAAAAAAAAQIDERIEEyExQQVRI2GB/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwAldXFrBFJNeTJDZW5zNJJ0J7l+O+PoKy7WX/kOtz6jofF7/ZlIZ0QSxtbrjBwGwMHB3xUnFfEcNpdS8OTcOm/t+Vch52Rps4OUwDvk9d9wa1HDHDWnW8zW9hadhCOR7zncuzNjKxlj1x1Pl41lixrFGh267l6+IP6DZEg3VxBntlxGHx/TTu28T1PzA7qu3GiWcxyqGJvxIcfSiI2G1KK9UzXtB7a9Gdm0S5j/ALMqyjwbY1RljktWxJEyE+PT1rYUA431W30rh65mn3yvKqY95icAetL30863PgObYLVSRzOMDH76VEZGSIscEDpjvoRp140nY+9zybLEFJyT3VozZXfIQnK5AyyB96SmKtblGjpL2we1w7gpJbsB+LIIz5VUy6Z5l5WyfYbGMeO1XZgQVikJSRgSFbfmHfUJA5iXix8Vbasrl/Q00KvIU9nIboeQ0zDwEuWATv2pViVsmNi30IpyKOgkbPgRQ6OjP6jkOhBB8DsahlDROpQcueqsdqtG3cAENj5bVxhXfmw2OuT1rmj2zUSaNEWBinniUfdBDfVgTV61t4rWLs4ECLksR4k7k1LXVfFBaUUlLXjhzsFUs3Qb15TxFctxTxIYQxOn6exGR0eU/p09a0/8Q+IG0rTRb2e97cns4QO4958hvWW0Ky5IbfTrJ8zy7M4O697MfkPrilc9vxE+2awkvLCWmvZaNaza3qk4js7Y9nC+GbJJwSBuTv7PrQDQ+HNJ13iSXiHR+I2kjiue3ljMLJPH38pYn3TvuB0yKt8ecU2OkStw1d6Ct5YLAjMJLnsudeo5MA7gjr41q+HeH9KsUS20q0eCK6Cz3XbMWk5B7qtknqdsdMBqZw41MqUJ5cnKt/DQ6XA4TtZrcN9qHMxbHsKPdXHXpv8AMmlutEspgSiGJvFD+VES+etMZ6beNUtNCvcae0zMXXD1zGxa2lWQ/wDqaHTQTwLyXKFD3ZG36Vs2eqt9cwwWkst0R2EaFnz0wKWr8fir14GI6y59+TLIwYZ5sfA7U1fZ78Hu3FCdBvmvbd05VDwMUcnfJySPQYHlRlUdkBZVA+dR8mNxbn9FCMnJJmzpaSlquYiioby4S1t3lcgBR1NTfSvM/wCKOuNK0Wg2cnLJcf3mB9yMdfXp61xnv7AJuZuI9cl1h1c2ynktQG5SFHU+ZGfStnwhp0MkcmoTqxWbaAglW5N/ayD3n6YrJ6LYG4nisYmP2cpmTlfZEGM+vu+ZPdXokcqooVQFC7ADurXpMHJvJX+C/U5mlxRPNaO/KY7iNipyv2mAScvyIKmrNpGttzsWLyyHLv0z4YHcB+tUxPSm4p1YkntISd01phPtRimNL8aH9vTTPRcAS60tY7+Ies/ZdOFrGcs+HZR34Psjzbf/ABrQPcKqlmOFAySe4V5ndztrvEgd1LRRHtXHhthfQfUmgzX2sbtmmOOVJBThuyW1so40bmkPtSMp76Tj7VJLDSBbW0nJc3jdmpXZgvVj6f7ojbqUIyZW8CVGBXn3FN8+o67clV5ks07CID7zdW/Svn8EdzLtlPPXbx6R9D0orhSMwVSScADNUDwM4j1aDR9Kmu7h+VEUk145YRz3ctxq+oOsU1yec85xyIOgB+AFFP4h6zJrmuppNuS1rakSXJGcFuqr5df+ql0SGS7u+SZR9mtwsky/i68i58CRkg52UjvriirpSgLtJefgd4fs/sFkXkUrc3BDyg7lR91fIHJ+LGifbYqs8hZiWJJJzvURkxVqJUrSJtVt7L3b/Gu7f40OMtJ2lHxA2Ee3+NcZ6HCSu7Q42rh7ZW4n1NLbT2R2ADglv+I6+pwPOs3w5YSyQG4+1AXFw3O3tb+e4qHXJhqurJZKcxlssB+Bf1O/nRaLSYeRZFdlY9OUYqN+TzLax7KPSY3rkScSancaNo08zchbAUbbkn8/WvNWlawgjXsw5AJck4Ge/wA960PGDyS38Gnm4Z0t17V+/lY+6N/WgM0MrABzHOFORvyMD4+FZdNj4xv9gdTfK9fo+oay3H/EKaFo0jggzP7EaE+8x6fr5VpZ5RDEzt3CvG9TmPFnE7zlBLp9kSkQDY5n+83qMeVFT0NL1sqadpS2di1zelpJJSZJHG/Ox8B3kk1r9Msv5dYRwMB2pPPNjoXPUfIDCj5UN0jS4P5sWgB7G0wW8GlO6j/Ee18yK0DrT3R42p5v6JZ6W+KKzGoWNWHWoHWnkxRoiJ3rg1cRSYruwRebeqOs3gs7F3Bw7DlWro+NZHiK4OoaktjE2ADybeJ6/v4VndqJdBxPKtFTSEMjy3kto8olICMjDZRnpkg95760S31vaI8na3sQQEsshzkD5/rV6z09IIkjRVcKu37FAuNboJYxacFCPdvglW6IuC35Dzr5+n3b8/Sov45MrDJLcmS7uTma5YyPt08B6VJy0/FLiqCWlont7ez0HiHi3VNchbTNM0yW2lm9kzSsMID1xnGTimJpo0LRwiRBpNkjiXB7SQ7KPXv+Zq3yRzNyHEbZyQGKnPyq3oOnyXevzSSo3Y6dErRk75d8gt5AfU0lhl5LSplLLamdou6Xpn8vsY4C3aSDLSyd7uTlj6mpnioqYqheKrXJeiZvYGlhfmyuCMdKrybe+MUZliYHZcg+BqBow4xj1FEmc0COQHcb00x0SaADOBjNQvFiu7OcQNq90un6fNcvtyr7Oe8npWO4fa2e9lmvJcONl5wRkn3vyHlRHja9aS9jsITkxe0w8XPQfvuq7pkEtnZxwkF41HR05hnv+NI9Zk8cEb4J87LwRWTmjcsB3jesTqVy1/q91cFueOL+hEfHHvH1o/rz2mn6bcXUEZiuRhY1XI5nJwOnrvWat4BbwpCDnkGD8T3/AFpTBHnZpnr4LiuIp5FNNNix64IGSPl5+RR+Mcw/X6111HqIjSXTLl7eaPdWjbbfxB2PmDVZp1JxKrEKfaUkI3mD+pq3BdIqhQGQDpnOKmOGioqREnFOqWpI1zSRMmf79uQreYAwfMDpRmx1jStRIW1vFErdIpx2bH4AnY+RqoJ0b2ZUx8T/AKyKG32j6bqCuGVlYjDcpKnz8fPNHHUZofvaArDjpetM1MtuUOHUrnpmq7w1lYv57o2U0y8M8IP9iUhl9D+WKIW3F8AIj1nT5rNzt2sILKf8evkCacjrcb8V4YtXTX7nyE3iofqk0VhZTXU2yRIWPx/f50Ztnt76LtdPuYrpO/s2ww+ancVgv4m6hm2j0+IhoxKPtBVvvdVTPj3/AA28adm01tPwYNaemZTRBLfas97KTzKxkbHex6egP/1WwjuWeMdsscn/ACHKfWqOhaZNa2SLzkSNln9kEZO/f3b1fnZbWGSWfsTHGpZj0OB12NSMtdymxyE5Rk+K7iO71e3tYQRHaJ2sqk59sjCj0yfOh4GBUNvLJcB7ucYmunMrDwHRR6VMKcxzxnQpdcq2IaYwp7kLjPfTCQfdNEAf/9k

Comment: Lo que le recomendaría es convertir ese código de Base64 a bitmap para poder mostrarlo correctamente. [Revisa esta respuesta, que quizás pueda ayudarte.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36975628/2576595)

Comment: Ya probe con un codigo para decodificar el string de Base64, lo probe en un decoder online y me muestra las imagenes pero en C# me da el siguiente error: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.  
No entiendo por que.

Comment: Tambien probe otra imagen de ejemplo de internet en Base64 y esa funciona bien. No entiendo.

Comment: En android es asi - > android.util.Base64.decode(MyStringBase64,android.util.Base64.DEFAULT)

Comment: @OsAndNoTi gracias, bastante cerca. Quedo asi: byte[] image64 = Android.Util.Base64.Decode(ImageBase64, default);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has intentado usando esta clase Util/Base64 ?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64

```
public static byte[] decode (byte[] input, 
            int flags)

try
{
    //.....

    //Decodificar el cadena base quitando los "=" extras al final si estan presentes
    byte[] image64 = Base64.decode(imagenBase64, Base64.NO_PADDING);
    
    //Decodificar la cadena base64 usando el estandar RFC 3548 seccion 4
    byte[] image64 = Base64.decode(imagenBase64, Base64.URL_SAFE);
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    string LineErrorNumber = "Error en linea: " + Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7) + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message;
}
```

Como se puede apreciar con el segundo parametro `Flags` se permite mas control sobre la decodificacion de la cadena y en tu caseo el `NO_PADDING` podria ser el que te interesa

Dichos flags/banderas se pueden combinar, dependiendo de que quiera lograr

```
byte[] image64 = Base64.decode(imagenBase64,  Base64.URL_SAFE + Base64.NO_PADDING + Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Aca dejo mas tipos de flags como se mencionan en el enlace que ya compartí

```
CRLF
Added in API level 8

public static final int CRLF

Encoder flag bit to indicate lines should be terminated with a CRLF pair instead of just an LF. Has no effect if NO_WRAP is specified as well.

Constant Value: 4 (0x00000004)
DEFAULT
Added in API level 8

public static final int DEFAULT

Default values for encoder/decoder flags.

Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)
NO_CLOSE
Added in API level 8

public static final int NO_CLOSE

Flag to pass to Base64OutputStream to indicate that it should not close the output stream it is wrapping when it itself is closed.

Constant Value: 16 (0x00000010)
NO_PADDING
Added in API level 8

public static final int NO_PADDING

Encoder flag bit to omit the padding '=' characters at the end of the output (if any).

Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
NO_WRAP
Added in API level 8

public static final int NO_WRAP

Encoder flag bit to omit all line terminators (i.e., the output will be on one long line).

Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)
URL_SAFE
Added in API level 8

public static final int URL_SAFE

Encoder/decoder flag bit to indicate using the "URL and filename safe" variant of Base64 (see RFC 3548 section 4) where - and _ are used in place of + and /.

Constant Value: 8 (0x00000008)
```

Comment: Hola Mauricio, no comprendí la 2da parte de tu respuesta. Considero que mucho mas útil y simple seria un caso de uso (como usar la 1ra parte del código que pusiste en el código que puse yo). Ya deduje la respuesta correcta gracias a ti y a @OsAndNoTi pero por la recompensa considero que es justo que definas mejor tu respuesta o esperemos si alguien mas la completa. Gracias.

Comment: ya incluí 3 ejemplos de como se usan los flags (segunca para de mi respuesta) esto tambien es nuevo para mi asi que solo use resultados de busquedas.

Comment: byte[] image64 = Android.Util.Base64.Decode(ImageBase64, default);